# Play Framework: Sending request.body to WS using WS.put for any content type (maybe using byteArray?)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an api endpoint that takes in a put request for a file, authenticates it and sends the authenticated request to a remote web server endpoint. I am using play's WS object to make the remote put file call as follows. I tried using request.get.asBytes and it compiled fine but the remote server received an empty file.

```
def putFile(location:String, key:String) = Action.async {
   request =>
      val MAXCHUNKSIZE=10000000
      val path= getPath(location,key)
      val stringToSign= getStringToSign(location, key)
      val rawBody=request.body.asRaw
      val bodBytes = rawBody flatMap { x: RawBuffer => x.asBytes(MAXCHUNKSIZE) } getOrElse(Array.empty[Byte])
      println("Request bodybytes: "+bodBytes.isEmpty)

      val result = WS.url(path)
        .withHeaders("Date" -> formattedDate,  "Authorization" -> authStr(stringToSign), "Content-length" -> request.headers.get("Content-Length").toString, "Content-Type"->request.headers.get("Content-Type").getOrElse("application/octet-stream"))
        .put(bodBytes) map { response =>
      println("Response: "+response.body)
      Status(response.status)(response.body).as(response.ahcResponse.getContentType)
   }
   result
}
```

I have to confess, I have been a Java developer and very new to scala and play (1 month) and the last map function was given to me by my colleague. I am not fully able to comprehend it. Any help would be appreciated(1)

The result of the debugging println messages was that the bodBytes.isEmpty is true for text files which are not empty. Any help would be appreciated(2)

If I hardcode a string in place of bodBytes, it works and seems to send the request, but there is one issue. It tries to print the response.body and it seems to be stuck waiting. Whereas the file is already uploaded to the server. Any help would be appreciated(3)

The test file I am using is just a simple Lorem ipsum file and not bigger than 400 bytes. The reason I am using asRaw is because it can be a image, xml file etc. Any help preferably with scala code is appreciated.